# gethittestresult() returning null on images in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

Im doing a getHitTestResult() on a webview.I want to get the url of the image clicked on. it seems to be working fine with anchors, but not with images. i always get a null with images. so i even tried requestFocusNodeHref(Message m). still no url!

so what do i do?

```
        this.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            WebView webview = (WebView) v;
            WebView.HitTestResult result = webview.getHitTestResult();
            Log.d("MP","String->"+result.toString());
            Log.d("MP","Type->"+result.getType());
            Log.d("MP","URL->"+result.getExtra());
        }
```

Comment: Do you get IMAGE_TYPE as expected?

Comment: yeah. but i figured out the problem. it's supposed to be the scroll view which i've been using.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation the result type is IMAGE_TYPE only when the HTML content consist the img tag else it will return other value. So you can not get the URL at that time when the result type is IMAGE_TYPE